# Biopython installation issues: "ImportError: No module named bio"

Tags: python, biopython

I'm trying to install Python 2.7.5 and the latest version of Biopython (as well as the prerequisite NumPy) on Windows 8 x64.

I've tried running the installer files for all of these programs and although every time the install seems to go perfectly, when I test to see if Biopython is installed (as instructed by the biopython wiki) I get an error:

```
>>> import bio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bio
>>>
```

I have tried using both the x64 and x32 installers for all three programs, and I even tried using WinPython, which comes with NumPy preinstalled and has a package manager which I installed Biopython with. However, it had the same result.

Can anyone help? I have searched and found people having similar errors, although typically they aren't using windows at the time and so I've not had any luck using their remedies.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the Biopython package is `Bio`, not `bio` (see [the FAQ](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc5), which instructs you to check your version like so):

```
>>> import Bio
>>> print Bio.__version__
```

> If the `"import Bio"` line fails, Biopython is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about python on windows, but you can try to give the full path of the library using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path). I'll paste [that user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7779/sebastian-rittau) code so the answer can be complete:

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('module.name', 'C:\Python27\Lib')
foo.MyClass()
```

On windows, the default path should be something like:

```
C:\Python27\Lib
```

although if it was, you wouldn't have this issue (also not sure about the backslashes)...

**Backup** solution (from same previous link)...

```
import sys
# the mock-0.3.1 dir contains testcase.py, testutils.py & mock.py
sys.path.append('/foo/bar/mock-0.3.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If @David Cain's suggestion of using *"Import B"* (capital B) still does not work, then your scenario is similar to issues I had in the past when using Windows.

My solution was simple. After installing Biopython I noticed it was located in "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages".

***Solution:***

I then copied a directory called **"Bio"** from **"site-packages"** and pasted into **"C:\Python27\Lib"**. Voilla! Everything has been working since.

Answer (score 0):

I use Anaconda and I had this problem too. I realised that I was trying the `import Bio` within Anaconda2 directory and I got the same error, but if I try the `import Bio` out of Anaconda2 directory, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I could import it in PyCharm after package installation, and not inside of Jupyter (Anaconda).